# How to fix this "Execution failed: These columns are out of bounds." error?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've writen this function, but I'm getting an error "Execution failed: These columns are out of bounds." (in my translation). The line generating the error is `var CellName = sheet.getRange(1, i+1);`. And I got this result:

[image]

These are the logs:

[image]

And this the transcript:

[image]

The code is bellow. And my doubt is why the for loop stops at header7 and not all headers?

```
  var font_size = 12;
  var headers = "HEADER1 HEADER2 HEADER3 HEADER4 HEADER5 HEADER6 HEADER7 HEADER8 HEADER9";
  var arrayHeaders = headers.split(/[\s\t]+/);
     Logger.log("arrayHeaders = " + arrayHeaders);
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayHeaders.length; i++){
       Logger.log("arrayHeaders.length = " + arrayHeaders.length);
      var CellName = sheet.getRange(1, i+1);
      CellName.setValue(arrayHeaders[i]).setBackgroundRGB(34, 139, 34).setFontSize(font_size).setFontWeight("bold").setFontFamily("Arial");
      // There is no column 0, so i+1 to start
      sheet.setColumnWidth(i+1, 100);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code in the following function the script completed with no errors and the expected column headers were in each cell in the spreadsheet:

```js
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var font_size = 12;
  var headers = "HEADER1 HEADER2 HEADER3 HEADER4 HEADER5 HEADER6 HEADER7 HEADER8 HEADER9";
  var arrayHeaders = headers.split(/[\s\t]+/);

  Logger.log("arrayHeaders = " + arrayHeaders);

  for (var i = 0; i < arrayHeaders.length; i++){
    Logger.log("arrayHeaders.length = " + arrayHeaders.length);
    var CellName = sheet.getRange(1, i+1);
    CellName.setValue(arrayHeaders[i]).setBackgroundRGB(34, 139, 34).setFontSize(font_size).setFontWeight("bold").setFontFamily("Arial");
    // There is no column 0, so i+1 to start
    sheet.setColumnWidth(i+1, 100);
  }
}
```

I initially thought that because in the screenshot there were only 7 columns that getRange was failing because the column index it was attempting to get did not yet exist. During testing though I discovered that getRange creates new columns where needed.

I can only think that maybe you have protected ranges or frozen columns in your sheet? Try the function above in a fresh spreadsheet and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the new Google Spreadsheet editor doesn't insert new columns where needed anymore. So, I had to insert this if block:

```
  if ( (i+1) > sheet.getLastColumn() ) {
      sheet.insertColumnAfter(i);
  }
```

Comment: Glad you fixed it. Any chance you're going to upvote me for helping you get on the right track? "getRange was failing because the column index it was attempting to get did not yet exist."

Comment: Just to clarify answer which is essentially correct: sheet.insertColumnAfter(n) will fail with "columns out of bounds" when inserting a new column inside a set of existing columns. Inserting column(s) only after sheet.getLastColumn() will succeed.